# Win32: Returning a minimized window to top when application tab removed

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I need your help: I am unable to restore/activate minimized window when the window tab is removed from the taskbar.

Usualy I use:

```
if (IsIconic(hwnd)) {
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_RESTORE);
}
```

And this works nice.

But.

When the application tab is removed from taskbar using [ITaskbarList interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) calling `ShowWindow(SW_RESTORE)` fails.

Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, sounds unlikely.  Better focus on IsIconic() returning FALSE.  Try GetWindowPlacement() instead.

Comment: Anyway ShowWindow(SW_RESTORE) fails when the app tab removed.